# DropDownListFor, not behaving as it should be

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, dropdownlistfor

Well, I'm learning how to use MVC, basically I want to use a dropdown list, here's the code in the view:

```
 <div class="form-group"
              @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MateriaID, ViewBag.ListaDeMaterias as SelectList, "--Selecciona una materia--", new { @id = "DropDwn", @class = "form-control" })
  </div>
```

This is the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Tabla_Materias> ListaMaterias = db.Tabla_Materias.ToList();
        ViewBag.ListaDeMaterias = new SelectList(ListaMaterias, "MateriaID", "Nombre_Materia");
        return View();

    }
```

This is the script:

```
function AddNewStudent(EstudianteID) {
    $("#form")[0].reset();
    $("#StuId").val(0);
    $("#DropDwn option:selected").text("--Selecciona una materia--");
    $("#ModalTitle").html("Agregar nuevo Estudiante");
    $("#MyModal").modal();

}
```

And this is how it looks:

[image]

That thing in the red "square" should be a drop-down list

Comment: is this `<div class="form-group"` just a typo when you were creating this question? because you really should close this div tag... `<div class="form-group">`

Comment: `<div class="form-group"` is missing `>` at the end. Not sure if that's the issue. You can try and fix that.

Comment: First Correct your div tag closing than check your HTML markup using browser developer tools

Comment: What are your trying to do with that script? Remove the `$("#DropDwn option:selected").text("--Selecciona una materia--");` line of code (and if your trying to select the first option, its `$("#DropDwn").val("");`